# freeradius (v3.0.21) ignoring accounting requests

Tags: debian, freeradius

I have installed a new freeradius (3.0.21) in a Debian 11 server.
Trying to get it to work with OpenVPN now. I see this in debug (-X) mode

```
(0) Login OK: [user/password] (from client vpn.domain.com port 1 cli 192.168.1.211)
(0) Sent Access-Accept Id 160 from 10.10.0.11:1812 to 1.2.3.4:36525 length 0
(0) Finished request
Waking up in 4.9 seconds.
(1) Received Accounting-Request Id 27 from 1.2.3.4:45138 to 10.10.0.11:1813 length 126
(1) User-Name = "user"
(1) NAS-IP-Address = 1.2.3.4
(1) NAS-Port = 1
(1) Service-Type = Outbound-User
(1) Framed-Protocol = PPP
(1) Framed-IP-Address = 10.10.x.y
(1) Calling-Station-Id = "192.168.1.211"
(1) NAS-Identifier = "OpenVpn"
(1) Acct-Status-Type = Start
(1) Acct-Session-Id = "356C7060124B02C6AAA2ABC123ABC123"
(1) NAS-Port-Type = Virtual
(1) Not sending reply to client.
(1) Finished request
(1) Cleaning up request packet ID 27 with timestamp +28
Waking up in 4.9 seconds.
```

So it gets acct packets, but just ignores them (because it doesnt know how it should log them??)
Which files/sections should i have a look at?

Cant see any warnings/errors in the log. Just see the "Login OK" for the auth, nothing about acct.

I have this in sites-enabled

```
listen {
        type = acct
        ipaddr = *
        port = 0
        limit {
                max_connections = 16
        }
}

preacct {
        preprocess
        acct_unique
        suffix
        files
}
```

I have an older (v2.1.12) freeradius that logs to /var/log/freeradius/radacct/IP/detail..., but that was set up many years ago, and i dont remember if i had to do anything to get that working. And comparing conf between servers... cant find anything obvious, its just so many files and sections:)

I see that detail and detail.log files/modules are enabled in the new server too, with this in detail
`filename = ${radacctdir}/%{%{Packet-Src-IP-Address}:-%{Packet-Src-IPv6-Address}}/detail-%Y%m%d`

Tried enabling sql/sqlcounter modules, didnt help.